# How to build a matrix of strings in C

Tags: c

I create a matrix by

```
typedef struct matrix {
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **data;
} matrix;

matrix m;
m.rows = 5;
m.cols = 2;
m.data = malloc(sizeof(int *) * m.rows);
int item=123; // here is my question

for (int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++) {
    m.data[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * m.cols);

    for (int j = 0; j < m.cols; j++) {
        m.data[i][j] = item;
    }
}
```

but I struggle to adapt the array structure for strings (e.g., `char* item="something"`). Sorry for the naive question. I even found similar questions in SO, but coming from high-level languages like PHP, I still cannot fathom how strings are adapted in arrays considering the fact that string is an array itself.

Comment: Don't store pointers, it will fragment memory and make reallocation harder. `static unsigned nrc2idx(unsigned ncol, unsigned irow, unsigned icol)
{
unsigned ret;
ret = irow * ncol + icol;
return ret;
}`

Comment: @wildplasser isn't it beneficial in terms of memory (in a large set of data) to record pointers only for accessing the data?

Comment: Storing a two dimensional array of strings (or pointer to char) dynamically, as in your example, just adds an extra dimension. Replace `int` with `char *`, *and* allocate the space for each string in the inner loop (just before you assign each 2D item). That last part is the dangerous part, as it's easy to get it wrong and have writes out of bounds and the like.

Comment: Wildplassers comment refers to creating a one dimensional array (of ints, or char *), not an array of arrays. That way, you are more likely to have contiguous data (in particular in the case of ints or floats). You then need to adjust your indexing to make it "fake" two dimensional, as in their code example.

Comment: Using a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `char` is fine. Allocating a block of pointers and then allocating storage for each string assigning the beginning address to the next available pointer in turn is bread-n-butter C. While you can optimize numeric storage by indexing a 1D array as a 2D array, that doesn't apply to a collection of strings that can have wildly different lengths. Dynamically allocating a matrix in the same way is fine as well. Unless you need to micro-optimize for a specific circumstance, the savings are in the noise.

Comment: To adapt for strings, you don't care about `cols` (except the allocate `len + 1` char for storage). You will have a nul-terminated string. So the `rows` count is the only critical counting member of your struct. Even then if you keep a sentinel-`NULL` after your last allocated string, `rows` isn't required to iterate over the collection either.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to create a struct containing your "string class" implementation, then make a 2D array out of such structs. Creating some `char***` will only cause you grief and bad performance.

Comment: First: what is your *purpose*? Do you want to create a spreadsheet-like structure, containing some text-containing cells? Do you nedd to change/reallocate these cells? Do you need to change the dimensions of the grid?

Comment: @wildplasser besides the fact that I am trying to understand C logics in coding, the purpose of this attempt is to fill a temporary array with data retrieved from MySQL. I want to store n rows retrieved from MySQL in an array and send it to a thread (a thread pool of pthread to be precise) as the argument (where the data are processed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the string object implementation and the matrix separated. The most simplistic string object would be something like:

```
typedef struct {
  size_t length;
  char* str;
} str_t;
```

Then we can create a 2D array of such strings:

```
str_t strings [rows][cols];
```

Or in case you need dynamic memory allocation, this is equivalent but allocated on the heap:

```
str_t (*strings)[cols] = malloc( sizeof(str_t[rows][cols]) );
...
free(strings);
```

Then populate the 2D array as you would have done with one made of `int`. Except strings have to be assigned with `strcpy` rather than the assignment operator `=`. And in this case we also which to store the length.

Also, the sole benefit of using `char* str` for the string rather than a fixed length array `char str[30]` is that we can adjust the size to match the data being stored:

```
  size_t length = strlen(some_items[i][j]);
  strings[i][j].str  = malloc(length + 1);
  strcpy(strings[i][j].str, some_items[i][j]);
```

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) 
{
  typedef struct {
      size_t length;
      char* str;
  } str_t;

  size_t rows = 5;
  size_t cols = 2;
  
  str_t (*strings)[cols] = malloc( sizeof(str_t[rows][cols]) );

  const char* some_items[5][2] = 
  {
    {"here", "are"}, 
    {"some", "random"}, 
    {"strings", "and"}, 
    {"here", "are"}, 
    {"some", "more"},
  };

  for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<cols; j++)
    {
      size_t length = strlen(some_items[i][j]);
      strings[i][j].str  = malloc(length + 1);
      strcpy(strings[i][j].str, some_items[i][j]);
      strings[i][j].length = length;
            
      printf("%s ", strings[i][j].str);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  free(strings);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the same approach as was used for integers, this will allocate rows and columns of strings. Each string can have up to length - 1 characters.
Each memory allocation should be checked to make sure it was successful. That check is omitted here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    char ***strings = NULL;
    size_t rows = 5;
    size_t cols = 2;
    size_t length = 41;

    //allocate memory
    strings = malloc ( sizeof *strings * rows);
    //iterate through rows
    for ( size_t eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; ++eachrow) {
        strings[eachrow] = malloc ( sizeof **strings * cols);
        //iterate through cols
        for ( size_t eachcol = 0; eachcol < cols; ++eachcol) {
            //allocate length for string
            //string can hold up to length - 1 characters
            strings[eachrow][eachcol] = calloc ( sizeof ***strings, length);
            //put something in the string
            sprintf ( strings[eachrow][eachcol], "%2lu row : %2lu col", eachrow, eachcol);
        }
    }

    //print strings
    for ( size_t eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; ++eachrow) {
        for ( size_t eachcol = 0; eachcol < cols; ++eachcol) {
            printf ( "%s      ", strings[eachrow][eachcol]);
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }

    //release memory
    for ( size_t eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; ++eachrow) {
        for ( size_t eachcol = 0; eachcol < cols; ++eachcol) {
            //free eachcol
            free ( strings[eachrow][eachcol]);
        }
        //now free each row
        free ( strings[eachrow]);
    }
    free ( strings);

    return 0;
}
```

Another route is to use a Variable Length Array (VLA). If VLA's are not supported then constant dimensions could be used, `char (*strs)[2][41]` and allocate rows as needed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    size_t rows = 5;
    size_t cols = 2;
    size_t length = 41;
    char (*strs)[cols][length] = NULL;//Variable Length Array

    //allocate memory
    strs = calloc ( sizeof *strs, rows);
    //iterate through rows
    for ( size_t eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; ++eachrow) {
        //iterate through cols
        for ( size_t eachcol = 0; eachcol < cols; ++eachcol) {
            //put something in the string
            sprintf ( strs[eachrow][eachcol], "r %2lu : c %2lu", eachrow, eachcol);
        }
    }
    //print strings
    for ( size_t eachrow = 0; eachrow < rows; ++eachrow) {
        for ( size_t eachcol = 0; eachcol < cols; ++eachcol) {
            printf ( "--%s  ", strs[eachrow][eachcol]);
        }
        printf ( "\n");
    }
    //release memory
    free ( strs);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking just replacing int with `char*` will make it a matrix of strings:

```
int main() {
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 5;

    char * * * matrix = malloc(sizeof (char **) * rows);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof (char*) * cols);
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = "hello";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But as others have commented above holding an array of arrays (of arrays) has it's own problems that you may run into later on...

Better to make it into a single dimensional array.
We can think of it this way:
For 3 rows and 4 columns we will have a total of `3 * 4 = 12` entries in the matrix.

We can generalise this into `r * c = n`. Therefore for a matrix of `foo`s we need to allocate a slice of memory `sizeof(foo) * rows * cols`

Then in order to find the correct position in the array for a particular entry say the 3nd column on the 2rd row.
eg:

```
[01][02][03][04]
[05][06][**][08]
[09][10][11][12]
```

We need to find call up the 7th item in the array.
We can generalise that to `p = col + (row * numCols)` or as for our example `7 = 3 + (2 * 4)`

```
int main() {
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 5;

    char ** matrix = malloc(sizeof (char *) * rows * cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            // We need to actually allocate some memory for the string to live :) 
            matrix[j + (i * cols)] = malloc(sizeof(char[10]));
            sprintf(matrix[j + (i * cols)], "%2d", j + (i * cols));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Add a bit of code to print out the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
        printf("%s", matrix[j + (i * cols)]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And we get the result:

```
 0  1  2  3  4 
 5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 
15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24
```

Freeing the memory after we're done with it is left as an exercise for the reader.

Hope this helps a little :)

Disclaimer: I'm no expert in C so anyone please let me know how this can be improved

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adapt your `struct matrix` to store a collection of strings, then as mentioned in the comment, there is no need to store `cols`, each string will be nul-terminated marking the end. For general input, you can simply allocate a pointer for each new string entered by the user. If reading 10,000+ strings from a file, then you benefit for adding another counter `allocated` and when `instance.rows == allocated`, you would reallocate doubling the number of pointers allocated. That way you can accommodate 1M rows with only 20 reallocations. (the exact growth scheme is up to you)

For purposes here, we will allocate one pointer per-row. (and with `realloc()` backed by `mmap`, the reallocation penalty is largely mitigated anyway)

To keep it as close to your original as possible, you could rewrite your struct as:

```
typedef struct strings {
    size_t rows;        /* cols not needed for strings `\0` marks end */
    char **str;
} strings;
```

You can declare your instance as:

```
    strings s = { .rows = 0 };      /* instance of struct initialized zero */
```

To collect your strings, simply read input into a fixed buffer and then allocate your pointer and storage for the line of input as required, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */
...
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* temporary buffer to hold input */
    ...
    /* read lines from stdin until ENTER on blank line */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) && *buf != '\n') {
```

Always reallocate using a temporary pointer so if `realloc()` fails and returns `NULL` you don't overwrite your original pointer address with `NULL` creating a memory-leak:

```
        size_t len;
        /* allocate new pointer */
        void *tmp = realloc (s.str, (s.rows + 1) * sizeof *s.str);
        if (!tmp) {     /* validate every allocation */
            perror ("realloc-s.str");
            break;
        }
        s.str = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block of pointers to s.str */
```

Now with your pointer allocated, simply trim the `'\n'` from the end of `buf` saving the length and allocate `len + 1` chars of storage and copy from `buf` to the new block of memory and increment your `.rows` count, e.g.

```
        buf[(len = strcspn(buf, "\n"))] = 0;        /* trim \n save len */
        if (!(s.str[s.rows] = malloc (len + 1))) {  /* allocate len + 1 bytes */
            perror ("malloc-s.str[rows]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (s.str[s.rows++], buf, len + 1);     /* copy buf to s.str[rows] */
    }
```

(**note:** on allocation failure you simply `break` from the read-loop, your original pointer to your data is still good and you can use the data up to the point of failure)

When you are done reading, you can use your strings however you need. Don't forget to free each allocated string and then free the pointers, e.g.

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.rows; i++) {           /* loop outputting results */
        printf ("s.str[%2zu] : %s\n", i, s.str[i]);
        free (s.str[i]);    /* free storage for each string when done */
    }
    free (s.str);           /* free pointers */
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 1024       /* if you need a constant, define one (or more) */

typedef struct strings {
    size_t rows;        /* cols not needed for strings `\0` marks end */
    char **str;
} strings;

int main (void) {
    
    char buf[MAXC];                 /* temporary buffer to hold input */
    strings s = { .rows = 0 };      /* instance of struct initialized zero */
    
    puts ("enter strings, [ENTER] alone when done");
    
    /* read lines from stdin until ENTER on blank line */
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) && *buf != '\n') {
        size_t len;
        /* allocate new pointer */
        void *tmp = realloc (s.str, (s.rows + 1) * sizeof *s.str);
        if (!tmp) {     /* validate every allocation */
            perror ("realloc-s.str");
            break;
        }
        s.str = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block of pointers to s.str */
        
        buf[(len = strcspn(buf, "\n"))] = 0;        /* trim \n save len */
        if (!(s.str[s.rows] = malloc (len + 1))) {  /* allocate len + 1 bytes */
            perror ("malloc-s.str[rows]");
            break;
        }
        memcpy (s.str[s.rows++], buf, len + 1);     /* copy buf to s.str[rows] */
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.rows; i++) {           /* loop outputting results */
        printf ("s.str[%2zu] : %s\n", i, s.str[i]);
        free (s.str[i]);    /* free storage for each string when done */
    }
    free (s.str);           /* free pointers */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
./bin/matrix_of_strings
enter strings, [ENTER] alone when done
My dog has fleas
my cat has none
lucky cat!

s.str[ 0] : My dog has fleas
s.str[ 1] : my cat has none
s.str[ 2] : lucky cat!
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/matrix_of_strings
==32588== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32588== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32588== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32588== Command: ./bin/matrix_of_strings
==32588==
enter strings, [ENTER] alone when done
My dog has fleas
my cat has none
lucky cat!

s.str[ 0] : My dog has fleas
s.str[ 1] : my cat has none
s.str[ 2] : lucky cat!
==32588==
==32588== HEAP SUMMARY:
==32588==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==32588==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 2,140 bytes allocated
==32588==
==32588== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==32588==
==32588== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==32588== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

There is little penalty for allocating 1 pointer per-line. For example, reading 32,000 lines of data in this manner takes only a few miliseconds:

```
$ time ./bin/matrix_of_strings < dat/32kint.txt > /dev/null

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.001s
```

There are several ways you can put the pieces together. When handling strings, allocating for the pointer and then the string is standard practice as the length of each string can vary wildly. How you grow the number of pointers is up to you. There are a number of examples on this site showing how to use an additional counter and allocate blocks of pointers instead of one pointer per-row.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.